# Why overriding with more specific parameter type is allowed in android?

Tags: java, android, generics

I was looking through android samples and found a place in code I don't understand. Here's the code (taken from [here](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/blob/master/Presentation/Decktastic/app/src/main/java/com/commonsware/android/preso/decktastic/RosterFragment.java))
:

```
public class RosterFragment extends BrowseFragment
  implements OnItemViewClickedListener {

  // code

  @Override
  public void onItemClicked(Presenter.ViewHolder viewHolder,
                            Object o,
                            RowPresenter.ViewHolder rowViewHolder,
                            Row row) {
    ((LeanbackActivity)getActivity()).showPreso((PresoContents)o);
  }

  // code

}
```

I've decompiled `OnItemViewClickedListener` class with jd-gui, it is declared as follows

```
package android.support.v17.leanback.widget;

public abstract interface BaseOnItemViewClickedListener<T>
{
  public abstract void onItemClicked(Presenter.ViewHolder paramViewHolder, Object paramObject, RowPresenter.ViewHolder paramViewHolder1, T paramT);
}
```

[Javadoc](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v17/leanback/widget/BaseOnItemViewClickedListener.html) says the same about class definition.

Note the last parameter, it has type `T` in declaring interface, so it should have type `Object` according to [jls](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.8.1) as I understand it. But code compiles successfully, it turns out that overriding with `Row` parameter insted of `Object` is allowed. I tried to write the same construction myself and got these two classes:

```
interface A<T>{
    public void dodo(Integer a, Object b, Float c, T t);
}

class B implements A{
    @Override
    public void dodo(Integer a, Object b, Float c, String t) {
    }
}
```

Attempt to compile leads to several errors: `B is not abstract and does not override abstract method dodo(Integer,Object,Float,Object) in A` and `method does not override or implement a method from a supertype`

The question is: what makes `RosterFragment` code compilable?

Comment: Your class implements OnItemViewClickedListener. You decompiled BaseOnItemViewClickedListener. Why not just read (and point to) the javadoc of the class. If it doesn't have any, you shouldn't use that class anyway.

Comment: It's probably because the one youve decompiled is obfuscated? so the class name goes single letter

Comment: I've decompiled class because I thought javadoc can differ from real class - and that would explain the issue. But in that case it's all right about javadoc. And no class isn't obfuscated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its easy to see that `OnItemViewClickedListener` implements `BaseOnItemViewClickedListener<Row>` and not any general `BaseOnItemViewClickedListener<T>`.

The definition code is [here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/master/v17/leanback/src/android/support/v17/leanback/widget/OnItemViewClickedListener.java).

In Doc form, its [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v17/leanback/widget/OnItemViewClickedListener.html).

So, clearly the last parameter's `T` has been resolved to `Row`.

Hope it helps !